# syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'copy' pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a copy command in pyspark. as below. How to get rid of this error?

```
   spark.write.format("snowflake") \
                        .options(**config.sfparams) \
                        .option("query",  "copy into people_data from (select $1:Company_ID::varchar as Company_ID from  @company_stage/pitchbook/"+config.todays_date+"/Company/")\
                        .load()
```

Error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.load.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'copy'.
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't support `copy into` when read, which is indeed strange if you want to read and play with data frame.

Comment: sorry edited  my code, actually I want this code to be executed on snowflake using pysaprk

Comment: it is spark.write, please have a look

Comment: Does it support a `copy into` on a read?  In theory, this would execute the command and then return the results of the `copy into` into a df in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Copy doesnt work in pyspark. created a external table to read data directly from s3 and enabled autorefresh=true